# fat arrow not working coffescript?

Tags: coffeescript, this, arrow-functions

I have this code in a coffee-script class constructor:

```
@item.find("li").draggable( start: @startConnection, drag: @updateConnection).droppable( drop: @dropConnection )
```

With those three methods in the class:

```
startConnection:(ev,ui) =>
    @currentConnection = new Connection(ui.offset)

updateConnection:(ev,ui) =>
    @currentConnection.update(ui.offset)

dropConnection:(ev,ui) =>
    @currentConnection.finish(ui.draggable, ui.offset)
```

and I got :

```
   Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'finish' of undefined
```

when I drop the item but not when I update: it seems @currentConnection is correctly defined in update() but not in dropConnection().

Why? I don't get what's wrong?

Comment: Can you show the complete code?

Comment: Do you want to drag one list item on top of another?  The 'droppable' item is the target, the thing you drag the 'draggable' one onto.

Comment: I think I understand what happens: here is the code that better reflects my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/QxKb5/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally understood what happened: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/QxKb5/3/) is the code that better reflects my problem.

```
//-- code in jsfiddle --//
```

The drop callback is called on the object being dropped onto, which is not the object where the drag event occurred.

The object on which the list item is dropped was not dragged before, therefore @id is undefined.

Thx a lot, this was a stupid mistake, but it took me a while to understand.

Comment: Great catch, thank you for following up on this with a jsfiddle, it really helped me.